# factoring trig functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm having an issue with factoring trig functions. For example the following:
$$
x^2 \ cos(2x) + 2x \ sin(2x) \\ 
$$

I thought it was 
$$
x(x\ cos(2x) + 2 \ sin(2x)) \\ 
$$

But this is what my books gives me
$$
2x(x\ cos(2x) + sin(2x) \\ 
$$

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you take out $x$ as common, $$x\cos2x+2\sin2x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose, you can just view $\cos 2x=a$ and $\sin 2x=b$ as inert lumps.  You are then trying to factor $x^2a+2xb=x(xa+2b)=x(x\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x))$  Your book is wrong, too, as the $\cos$ term does not start with a factor $2$ but has one in the final answer.

Comment: this is actually part of a differentials problem and i followed dy = f'(x)dx so would it still be $ dy = x(xcos(2x) + 2sin(2x))dx$ ?

Comment: The factorization is independent of where the terms came from.  Yes, if that was $\frac {dy}{dx}$ you are correct.  A hint: to get the trig functions in the proper font, put a backslash before them.  So \cos gives $\cos$